# Stochastic Finance I am having difficulty with my homework questions. Brownian Motion

Tags: finance

A 2-dimensional process $(B_t^1,B_t^2),\ t \geq 0 $ is a standard 2-dimensional Brownian Motion if each $B_t$ is a standard Brownian motion and the $B_t^s$ are independent of each other. Let $ X_t = t^2 + \sin B_t^1 + B_t^1B_t^2$. Calculate $dX_t$, and explain why $X_t$ is a semimartingale.

Belwo is m final attempt at the solution. I am unsure of my justification of why it is a semi-martingale.

First $X_t$ is a function of $t$,$B_t^1$,$B_t^2$:

$$X_t=f(t,B_t^1,B_t^2)=t^2 + \sin B_t^1 + B_t^1B_t^2$$

The Ito lemma gives an expression for $df$:

$$df(t,B_t^1,B_t^2)=\frac{\partial f}{\partial t}dt+\frac{\partial f}{\partial B_t^1}dB_t^1+\frac{\partial f}{\partial B_t^2}dB_t^2+ \frac{1}{2}\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial^2 B_t^1}d[B_t^1,B_t^1]+\frac{1}{2}\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial^2 B_t^2}d[B_t^2,B_t^2]+\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial B_t^1 \partial B_t^2}d[B_t^1,B_t^2]$$

Since:

$ \frac{df}{dt} = 2t, \frac{df}{dB_t^1} = \ \text{cos}B_t^1 + B_t^2, \ \ \frac{df}{dB_t^2} = B_t^1   \frac{d^2f}{dt^2} =2 \ \  \ \  \ \frac{d^2}{d(B_t^1)^2} = -\text{sin}B_t^1  \frac{d^2f}{d(B_t^2)^2} = 0 $

Therefore:

$$df(t,B_t^1,B_t^2)=2tdt+\cos{B_t^1}dB_t^1+B_t^2 dB_t^1+B_t^1 dB_t^2-\frac{1}{2}\sin{B_t^1}d[B_t^1,B_t^1]+d[B_t^1,B_t^2]$$

Gathering like terms we get that:

$ (2t-\frac{1}{2} \ \text{sin} B_t^1)dt + ( \ \text{cos}B_t^1 + B_t^2, B_t^1)  \begin{bmatrix}
       dB_t^1      \\
       dB_t^2 
     \end{bmatrix} $
$= \mu(t,B_t^1,B_t^2)dt + \sigma(t,B_t^1,B_t^2) \begin{bmatrix}
       dB_t^1      \\
       dB_t^2 
     \end{bmatrix} $

Now

$ X_t = X_0 + \int_0^t(\cos B_s^1 + B_s^2) dB_s^1 + \int_0^t B_s^1dB_s^2- \frac{1}{2} \int_0^t \sin B_s^1 ds + \int_0^t 2sds $ where $ \int_0^t (\cos B_s^1 + B_s^2) dB_s^1 + \int_0^t B_s^1dB_s^2$ is a Martingale. And $ \frac{1}{2} \int_0^t \sin B_s^1 ds + \int_0^t 2sds$ is the Finite Variation process. Hence $X_t$ is a semi-martingale.

Comment: I changed \ \text{sin} to \sin.  That is standard.

Comment: Welcome to mathSE! what have you tried?

Comment: User is new, downvote is pointless...

Comment: Writing a question in the style appropriate for assigning a homework exercise is frowned on here.

Comment: Then it seems you are ready

Answer (score 0):

First $X_t$ is a function of $t$,$B_t^1$,$B_t^2$:

$$X_t=f(t,B_t^1,B_t^2)=t^2 + \sin B_t^1 + B_t^1B_t^2$$

The Ito lemma gives you a expression to $df$:

$$df(t,B_t^1,B_t^2)=\frac{\partial f}{\partial t}dt+\frac{\partial f}{\partial B_t^1}dB_t^1+\frac{\partial f}{\partial B_t^2}dB_t^2+\frac{1}{2}\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial^2 B_t^1}d[B_t^1,B_t^1]+\frac{1}{2}\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial^2 B_t^2}d[B_t^2,B_t^2]+\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial B_t^1 \partial B_t^2}d[B_t^1,B_t^2]$$

Therefore:

$$df(t,B_t^1,B_t^2)=2tdt+\cos{B_t^1}dB_t^1+B_t^2 dB_t^1+B_t^1 dB_t^2-\frac{1}{2}\sin{B_t^1}d[B_t^1,B_t^1]+d[B_t^1,B_t^2]$$

How the brownian motion are independent of each other:

$$df(t,B_t^1,B_t^2)=2tdt-\frac{1}{2}\sin{B_t^1}dt+\cos{B_t^1}dB_t^1+B_t^2 dB_t^1+B_t^1 dB_t^2$$

I let  to you see why is a semimartingale.

Comment: @Did I don't see very well were is the mistake

Comment: To show that it is a semi-martingale take $ X_t = X_0 + \int_0^t (\text{cos}B_s^1 +B_s^2)dB_s^1 + \int_0^t B_s^1d B_s^2 -\frac{1}{2} \int_0^t \text{sin}B_s^1ds + \int_0^t 2sds$ where $ \int_0^t (\text{cos}B_s^1 + B_s^2)dB_s^1 + \int_0^tB_s^1dB_s^2 $ is a Martingale. And $ \frac{1}{2} \int)0^t \text{sin}B_s^1ds + \int_0^t 2sds$ is the finite variation process. Hence $X_t$ is a semi-martingale.

Comment: @rlartiga You mean, in the version available when I posted a comment, or in the version revised following the indication in my comment?

Comment: @Did is my above attempt correct??

Comment: @Did then now is all ok then :)